# Jqplot graphics not displayed in the Bootstrap carousel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, jqplot

I'm testing the Jqplot graphics on the Bootstrap carousel. In the first slide (title: GRAPHIC 1) of the carousel the graphic appears, but in the second slide (title: GRAPHIC 2) the graphics are not generated.

I leave you the source code:

```js
// JAVASCRIPT

$(function() {
  $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;

  // GRAPHIC VERTICAL
  var dataGraphic = [5681, 5021, 4503, 3239, 2218, 1825, 197, 8];
  var nameData = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'];

  $.jqplot('chartTopSlide1', [dataGraphic], {
    grid: {
      background: '#ffffff',
      drawGridlines: false,
      drawBorder: false,
      shadow: false
    },
    height: 230,
    seriesDefaults: {
      renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
      rendererOptions: {
        barWidth: 25,
        shadowOffset: 0
      },
      pointLabels: {
        show: true
      }
    },
    axes: {
      xaxis: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
        ticks: nameData
      },
      yaxis: {
        borderWidth: 0,
        max: 6500,
        rendererOptions: {
          drawBaseline: false
        },
        show: false,
        showTicks: false
      }
    },
    highlighter: {
      show: false
    }
  });

  // GRAPHIC HORIZONTAL
  var dataGraphic3 = [805, 905, 1905, 2905, 3905, 4905, 5251, 16496];
  var nameData3 = ['MX', 'PT', 'US', 'FR', 'RU', 'IT', 'CN', 'ES'];

  $.jqplot('chartBottom', [dataGraphic3], {
    grid: {
      background: '#ffffff',
      drawBorder: false,
      shadow: false
    },
    series: [{
      renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
      escapeHTML: false
    }],
    seriesDefaults: {
      rendererOptions: {
        barWidth: 25,
        shadowOffset: 0,
        barDirection: 'horizontal'
      },
      pointLabels: {
        show: true
      }
    },
    axes: {
      xaxis: {
        max: 18000,
        borderWidth: 0,
        rendererOptions: {
          drawBaseline: false
        },
        show: false,
        showTicks: false
      },
      yaxis: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
        ticks: nameData3,
        pad: 50,
        tickOptions: {
          showGridline: false
        }
      }
    },
    highlighter: {
      show: false
    }
  });

  // GRAPHIC DONUTS
  var data1 = [
    [1, 78334],
    [2, 37092]
  ];
  var data2 = [
    [1, 78334],
    [2, 34396]
  ];
  var data3 = [
    [1, 78334],
    [2, 2859]
  ];
  var data4 = [
    [1, 78334],
    [2, 2366]
  ];
  var data5 = [
    [1, 78334],
    [2, 2199]
  ];

  var options = {
    height: 160,
    width: 160,
    grid: {
      background: '#ffffff',
      drawBorder: false,
      shadow: false
    },
    seriesDefaults: {
      renderer: $.jqplot.DonutRenderer,
      rendererOptions: {
        shadowOffset: 0,
  sliceMargin: 0,
  innerDiameter: 120,
  startAngle: -90
      }
    },
    seriesColors: ['#e1eaef', '#216b92']
  };

  $.jqplot('graphic1', [data1], options);
  $.jqplot('graphic2', [data2], options);
  $.jqplot('graphic3', [data3], options);
  $.jqplot('graphic4', [data4], options);
  $.jqplot('graphic5', [data5], options);
});
```

```css
/* ------------ STYLE ---------------- */

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  font-size: 5em;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

a,
a:active,
a:focus,
a:hover,
a:visited {
  color: #006a86;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.divToCenter{
 display: table;
}
.divToCenter .contentMiddle{
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

.device-content-top{
 border-bottom: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
 height: 300px;
}

.carousel{
 height: 299px;
}
.carousel-indicators{
 bottom: 0;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
.carousel-indicators li{
 background-color: #c6c6de;
 border: none;
 margin: 0;
 margin-right: 5px !important;
 width: 14px;
 height: 14px;
}
.carousel-indicators li:last-child{
 margin-right: 0 !important;
}
.carousel-indicators li.active{
 background-color: #808a92;
 width: 14px;
 height: 14px;
}

/* ----------------- TYPE --------------------- */

.typeDevice div{
 display: inline-block;
}
.typeDevice  .titleType{
 font-size: 16px;
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
}

/* ------------------- GRAPHICS ------------------------ */

.chartBottom{
 overflow-y: scroll;
}
.jqplot-point-label {
 color: #0079b4;
 font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>GRAPHICS OF JQPLOT</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.9/jquery.jqplot.min.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="app">
   <div class="device-content-top row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="deviceContentTop">
     <!-- ONLY CAROUSEL -->
     <div id="carouselGeneric" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="5000">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
       <li data-target="#carouselGeneric" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
       <li data-target="#carouselGeneric" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
       <div class="item active" id="slide1">
        <h2>GRAPHIC 1</h2>
        <div id="chartTopSlide1"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="item" id="slide2">
        <h2>GRAPHICS 2</h2>
        <div class="typeDevice">
         <div class="">
          <span class="titleType">TYPE 1</span>
          <div id="graphic1"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="">
          <span class="titleType">TYPE 2</span>
          <div id="graphic2"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="">
          <span class="titleType">TYPE 3</span>
          <div id="graphic3"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="">
          <span class="titleType">TYPE 4</span>
          <div id="graphic4"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="">
          <span class="titleType">TYPE 5</span>
          <div id="graphic5"></div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="device-content-bottom row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="deviceContentBottom">
     <h2>GRAPHIC 3</h2>
     <div id="chartBottom" class="chartBottom"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!-- SCRIPT -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.9/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.9/plugins/jqplot.pieRenderer.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.9/plugins/jqplot.donutRenderer.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.9/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.9/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqPlot/1.0.9/plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you give me a hand? Or tell me how I can solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Note: If you change the div of the graphs between the two slides, you can see that no graph appears on the second slide.

Answer (score 1):

I think when you use `DonutRenderer` you need to have some of the following options defined:

```
sliceMargin: 2,
innerDiameter: 110,
startAngle: -90
```

There are more options you can pass through obviously but I think those 3 are required.